# Script to search for a value and create a variable dynamically?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, variables, dynamic

Sorry if the question in the title is a bit vague, here's what I'm trying to accomplish:

Is there a script out there that can search a page (or page source) for a particular determined value (for example, a product ID "1234") and insert it dynamically or on-the-fly into a variable which can be used anywhere on the page if called?

For example:
I'm working on a site that uses a shopping cart/feed platform that is closed source, so I can't grab variables I need (such as the product ID, product price, and order ID), as they are "locked down" (so to speak). And I need to be able to grab them and dynamically insert them into click trackers/pixel URL strings.

I'm not sure if this is possible or if this is a much larger task at hand.

Answer (score 0):

A webpage might have many ways of showing a value, and it takes some human interpretation to determine what values are important. Example:

```
<div id="couponDisplay" class="inset hidden">Enter your coupon code: <input name="coupon"/></div>
<div id="cartRegion">
    <div class="cart">
        <div class="lolbx_quantityControl" data-initialValue="1" onKey="lolbx_notify()">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It may be that you're looking at a shopping cart page, and though the whole HTML is hundreds of lines long, the most important part of that page for you is the `data-initialValue="1"` part. That's less obvious to a computer. The first step for you might be the path the computer uses to reach the value you want, then see if you can replicate that.

I'm not sure if I understand what sort of system you're connecting to, though; I will say that using outside web services through "hacks" like this without their permission may be violating their terms of use (ie, grabbing Google Maps data to make your own map control with no Google branding)